# How can I change the Software Centre prices to GBP?

Tags: software-center, unity-dash

The pricing in the Software Centre and in the Dash is in USD. I don't live in the USA so this is not relevent to me. Is it possible to change to GBP or even EUR?

Answer (score 3):

It does not look like this is possible at the moment (however, I *might* be wrong). There is however a bug on the subject: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1002647

You could help out by going to the bug and click on "Does this bug affect you?".

It should be fixed! =)